# Angular 6 Subscription cleanup when clicking a button multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs

Say I have a contact us button with a subscription to a contact us service, which returns an observable after firing the http request.

If a user clicks the button 10 times and sends 10 emails (desired), will 10 concurrent subscriptions be running? If so, what's the best practice for subscription cleanup in this scenario?

Comment: It would be easier if you showed the code you are using since the answer very much depends on it.

Comment: You can check if the current subscription is closed or not. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html#instance-member-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid unsubscribing if you add a `take(1)` to the pipe when you subscribe - if you're subscribing multiple times

Alternatively, have a single subscription in the component with the button, which you initialize in `ngOnInit()` or in the `constructor`. Save a reference to the subscription in a `private contactSubscription: SubscriptionLike` property, and call `contactSubscription && contactSubscription.unsubscribe` in `ngOnDestroy()`

Comment: take(1) is a very concise way to handle my scenario, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

just save your subscription in a property and check if it exists, don't subscribe, if not then subscribe

```
cacheSub: Subscription;

contactUs() {
  if(!this.cacheSub) {
     this.cacheSub = this.service.cacheSub.subscribe(....);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

if you want to subscribe each time and clean each subscription then, you can do

```
cacheSub: Subscription;

contactUs() {
     this.cacheSub = this.service.cacheSub.subscribe(() => {
        // some code here if you need it
        this.cacheSub.unsubscribe();
     });
}
```

or

```
contactUs() {
    this.cacheSub && this.cacheSub.unsubscribe();
    this.cacheSub = this.service.cacheSub.subscribe(() => {
            // some code here if you need it
    });
}
```

Comment: I must clarify... I want to be able to click the button 10 times and send 10 emails, my question is more when the user clicks the button again, what happens or what should i do to the 1st subscription.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I didn't get what you mean, how should you send emails when you will subscribe to observable ?, it will be better if you will share your code

Comment: I can post the code in a bit, however, I have a function that gets called by a UI button that then subscribes to the service that calls a web api method to send the email.

Comment: @RandomUs1r I have updated my answer, please check if it's what you need

Comment: the bottom two solutions look great, but I wound up using take(1), thanks!